# How to add a fact to Drools

Tags: java, drools

i'm new with Drools and i have a few little problems.
I've allready written a Test-Rule-File just to see if it works.

I have a few Rules which conditions base on the Results of other Rules.
So far i handled it by manipulating Attributes in the Java-Objekts. So the following Rules can check these attributes.

But is it possible to add a fact to the knowledgebase without manipulating existing attributes?

Here a part of my DRL

```
 rule "Ist save" 
 no-loop true
 when 
      $p : Person(guarantor == true)
then 

    $p.setSave(true);
 end

rule "Ist trustworthy" 
 no-loop true
when
    $p : Person(ages > 25)
    Person(schufa == false)

then
modify($p) {setReliable(true);  }
end

rule "gets credit"
 no-loop true
 when 
    $p : Person(reliable == true && save == true)
then     
    $p.setGetsCredit(true);
end
```

The same question reworded: 
Actually i manipulate the Person with setting setSave(true). But if i wouldn't have the Attribute isSave in my Java Class. Would it be also possible to add the fact isSave to my knowledgebase?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing keeps you from defining a class capable of holding that information, a "save" value and a reference to a Person object, and insert that.